# How to determine what a pronoun is referring to

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity

Does the second "woman" in this sentence refer to a female supervisor?

> One woman, who had been working under an extremely verbally abusive supervisor, confronted the woman and was abruptly fired from her job.

Comment: Unless there's a more obvious candidate in preceding context. But it's not well phrased.

Comment: *The woman* refers to somebody, but the context doesn't make it explicit who it is. It's natural to *assume*, with only the single sentence, that it's referring to the supervisor, making the person a woman, but details from a previous sentences might make it clear that *the woman* was actually a coworker, a customer, or somebody else.

Comment: Thanks. I also think it refers to the supervisor being a woman too.

Comment: Note that "woman" isn't a pronoun.

Answer (score -1):

From the stated example, the parenthetical "*who had been working under an extremely verbally abusive supervisor*" is separate from the main idea and is added to clarify the identity of the first woman mentioned. The second time a woman is mentioned it is most unlikely to be the same one.

Without the middle part the sentence reads, "One woman [..] confronted the woman and was abruptly fired from her job." Apart from sounding a bit tinny to this ear it works just fine to get the meaning across.

We may be overly used to clarifying that we are talking about a woman, not a man, these days and that's fine. We should not be surprised when we end up talking about more than one woman at a time.

Comment: If the two uses of "woman" refer to the same one, then this means the woman confronted herself. That doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @Barmar; Your comment is very good. It might make a better answer. I can't see why this was down voted.